# Javascript : loop in conditional based on array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, if-statement

I would like to check multiple conditions based on an extensible array of variables. What's the method to check them ?

For example:

```
a = 0;
b = 1;
c = 0;

if (a == 0 && b == 0 && c == 0) {
    console.log("all a,b,c variables == 0")
}
```

Good. Now for an array ?

```
arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", ...];

if (for i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++ { arr[i] == 0 && }) {
    console.log("all arr variables == 0")
}
```

I think I'm going the wrong way here... Is there a solution check a lot of statements based on an array ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: *"I think I'm going the wrong way here..."* Since your code has syntax errors, definitely yes. What exactly are you trying to achieve? *"Is there a solution check a lot of statements based on an array ?"* What exactly does that mean?

Comment: what means `["a", "b", "c", "d" ...]`?

Answer (score 4):

How about [Array.prototype.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)?

```
const array = [0, 0, 0];
array.every(x => x === 0); // true
```